# Can a dropdowns options be selected only once per list item?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am probably going about this all wrong.

I have a plugin made that is for loading an image with description and a name chosen from a drop-down list.
The images are used for a single page website's backgrounds, so I want them to have the names select-able only once from the drop-down.
So that multiple images can't be assigned to one sections background.
The next entry wont have the option available or won't be select-able in the name drop-down.

Is this possible or is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT- This is for a drop-down in the backend plugin form.

Comment: I answered your question with a simple array. For future questions it is best to include some code to help us help you. I don't know how you are constructing the dropdown menus so you are going to have to adjust my answer to your code. Lots of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with Javascript / Jquery for a more graceful way but for sure I know you can use Octobercms AJAX and Session to get this done. (I like to use what OctoberCMS provides) Here is working code I made adhoc using just the CMS page of October.

1. I used three partials
2. I used jquery to watch `<select>` tags and to run Ajax request
3. I used OctoberCMS Session to store values

This is the partials' markup code: You will noticed that this will only print the `<option>` values for the select element.

```
<option value="">Select</option>
{% for a in array %}
<option value="{{ a }}" {% if a == selected %}selected{% endif %}>{{ a }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

The partials' PHP code will change per each partial but for example here is first one: Here you are starting an array. Then we check for values in the session with `Session::get('select2')`. Notice the `-1`; When you `unset($array[$select2])` it is looking for the index key. Our array really looks like `[0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>5]` and it is easy just to subtract one to find the key index. We also get away with `unset($array[-1])` because there is no index key `-1` in our array. Next we are getting the selected value for the `<select>` by calling its own session value with `Session::get('select1')`. Then we are pushing the constructed array to the partial.

```
function onStart() {
    $array = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $select2 = Session::get('select2') - 1;
    unset($array[$select2]);
    $select3 = Session::get('select3') - 1;
    unset($array[$select3]);
    $this['selected'] = Session::get('select1');
    $this['array'] = $array;
}
```

The CMS Page markup looks like this: The first three items are calling the select options by their partial. Lets look at the Jquery. I am watching for `#selectOne` to change and then I am calling the request. We update every other partial. We push the name attribute and the value with the request.

```
<select name="select1" id="selectOne">
{% partial 'select1' %}
</select>
<select name="select2" id="selectTwo">
{% partial 'select2' %}
</select>
<select name="select3" id="selectThree">
{% partial 'select3' %}
</select>

{% put scripts %}
<script>
$('#selectOne').change(function(){

    $(this).request('onUpdate', {
        update: {
            select2: '#selectTwo',
            select3: '#selectThree'
            },
        data: {
            value: $(this).val(),
            name: $(this).attr("name")
            }
    })//*/
});

$('#selectTwo').change(function(){

    $(this).request('onUpdate', {
        update: {
            select1: '#selectOne',
            select3: '#selectThree'
            },
        data: {
            value: $(this).val(),
            name: $(this).attr("name")
            }
    })//*/
});

$('#selectThree').change(function(){

    $(this).request('onUpdate', {
        update: {
            select1: '#selectOne',
            select2: '#selectTwo'
            },
        data: {
            value: $(this).val(),
            name: $(this).attr("name")
            }
    })//*/
});
</script>
{% endput %}
```

The CMS Page function: Here if the value is greater than null we are putting the information into the Session with `Session::put(key, value)`. If the value option is 'select' which has a value of 0 (not greater than null) we are removing the select value from the session.

```
function onUpdate() {
    if (Input::get('value') > null) {
        Session::put(Input::get('name'), Input::get('value'));
    } else {
        Session::forget(Input::get('name'));
    }
}
```

Again there are numerous ways to do this but I am sure you can adapt this code fairly easy to a plugin's component.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't notice the backend tag and you don't mention in your question. I don't think you do the way I originally suggested in the backend. So here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4E5Q/1/) that I know you could use in the backend. Here is the javascript used and you will have to adjust it for your use.

```
  function preventDupes( select, index ) {
      var options = select.options,
          len = options.length;
      while( len-- ) {
          options[ len ].disabled = false;
      }
      select.options[ index ].disabled = true;
      if( index === select.selectedIndex ) {
          alert('You\'ve already selected the item "' + select.options[index].text + '".\n\nPlease choose another.');
          this.selectedIndex = 0;
      }
  }

  var select1 = select = document.getElementById( 'select1' );
  var select2 = select = document.getElementById( 'select2' );

  select1.onchange = function() {
      preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
  };

  select2.onchange = function() {
      preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
  };
```

Comment: Sorry Pettis I should have stated that it was for the back end. I edited my question to reflect that. Forgive my noobisms, where would I put this Javascript? I understand what you suggest, great work! I am just a bit new to OctoberCMS and its MVC ways.

Comment: Thought I had responded to this. Yeah you can add this to the create and update htm file found in `author/plugin/controllers/configs/` Put the script at the bottom of the page would be best I believe.